# Get attachments by user

Tags: theme-development, attachments, media-library, uploads

Is there a way to get attachments by user? I need a way to display all the images uploaded by a specific user.  (I probably need the attachment IDs so that I can use `wp_get_attachment_url` to display them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [custom query for this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
$user_id = 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'author' => $user_id) );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
   the_title();
endwhile;
```

This will show all the attachment titles for user with user id 1. You can use `get_the_ID()` in the loop to get the attachment ID.